# Regex matching for multiple html tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to find a regex that matches if all tags in a piece of HTML are empty, regardless of attributes and if there are nested tags.

My code essentially looks like this:

```js
const emptyHtmlTagRegex = new RegExp(/<[^/>][^>]*><\/[^>]+>/);

if (emptyHtmlTagRegex.test(this.htmlContent)) {
  // Output placeholder
};
```

And I'd like to get a match when `this.htmlContent` is for example:

```html
<ul><li class="class-name"></li></ul>
```

```html
<p></p>
```

But not match if `this.htmlContent` is:

```html
<p>nomatch</p><ul><li></li><ul><p></p>
```

The regex does not match the entire string so the test method reports false positives if there are trailing empty tags: [Regex 101 sample](https://regex101.com/r/JvD3MY/1)

I've also tried to use `this.htmlContent.replace(regex,'')` and look for empty strings but that failed because of compatibility issues with the testing framework I use.

Comment: Parsing HTML using regex is a bad idea: there is no adequate way to check nesting, there is no easy way to check bracket balance, you need to support paired and single tags, ... Use html parser.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and it seems to work. Will write an answer for people stumbling upon this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@markalex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21363224/markalex) I learned that it is better to do this by actually parsing the HTML.

For anyone stumbling upon this in the future, my solution looks like this:

```js
const isEmptyHtml = (html) => {
  // Create a new element and add the input html string
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  element.innerHTML = html;

  // Use innerText to get the rendered text from the html element created
  const trimmedContent = element.textContent.trim();

  // Returns true if the contents does not contain any text - all tags are empty
  return trimmedContent === '';
};

if (isEmptyHtml(this.htmlContent)) {
  // Output placeholder
};
```

This works for the pieces of HTML I've tested so far.